# How can I solve problems with Dropout?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, neural-network

Hello I am making a Neural Network code, adjusting the code to avoid overfitting but when using Dropout in my first Input Layer and hidden layer I have the following error:

[image]

Comment: You should use `Dropout(rate=0.1)` instead of `Dropout(p=0.1)`.

Answer (score 1):

once more, the drop `rate` (or `‘rate’`) in Keras determines the odds of dropping out neurons – instead of keeping them. In effect, with respect to the parameter p defined by Srivastava et al. (2014) when discussing Dropout, rate thus effectively means 1−p. If 75% of the neurons are kept with p=0.75, rate must be 0.25.

you must this code if `p = 0.1`

```
Dropout(rate=0.9)
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks! now i can